# What to say during a mageifah

Tags: tefilla

We are being asked to say the parsha of ketores and tehillim during the current Coronavirus outbreak. Why are we not saying on a daily basis those sections of the Torah that discuss past mageifahs to strike Klal Yisroel? In specific, the eigel and Korach’s rebellion. I would think that reciting these chapters would spur us on to better ourselves by learning the lessons from those two mageifahs

Comment: Whatever inspires you to Teshuva Tefilla and Tzedaka should be great.

Comment: This seems like a valid question that should have real answers. I don't see why it was closed as opinion based.

Comment: In case you were wondering about the connection between *k'tores* and a plague, see [*B'midbar* 17:11-15](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0417.htm#11). R' Gil Student [summarizes](https://www.torahmusings.com/2020/03/why-do-epidemics-happen/) the discussion of the Mabit on this topic and mentions the Mabit's suggestion to study the passages relating to *k'tores* ([*Sha'ar HaT'fila* 16](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14113&st=&pgnum=43)).

Comment: @Eliyahu do you know who is asking to read this one thing and not the other as outlined in the question? If you do, identify them and then someone can ask them.

Comment: @DoubleAA Obviously no one is saying "Don't you dare say the Ketores!" However, I get asked 5-10 times a day to say specific Tehillim or the like, including from major Jewish organizations and Gedolim, and I have never been told to say the Ketores. I would imagine most other people in large Jewish communities have had the same experience.

Comment: You're welcome to start a chain email with whatever you want and if it sounds convincing people will spread it.